# install scikit-learn on python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I tried to use the following two commands to install scikit-learn on Mac OS:

```
pip3 install -u scikit-learn

pip3 install scikit-learn
```

I did not know `"-u"` stands for upgrade and used the `-u` command first. Then when I used the second command, I got the following error message:

```
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit-learn-0.18.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: scikit-learn
  Running setup.py install for scikit-learn … error
```

What should I do? thanks.

Comment: Add the complete error traceback.

Comment: Also to format and edit your question see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work **and** https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks in addtion might be worth a try: `sudo pip install --no-cache-dir scikit-learn` this installs it globally as sudo ignoring any previous cached versions.

Comment: the `-u` option you are talking about is actually `-U` which means `Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. This process is recursive regardless of whether a dependency is already satisfied.`

Comment: and you might wanna try anaconda python version it comes with all the packages inbuilt and installed you can ever use.

Comment: For future reference it would have been helpful to mention the operating system you are working with. For example, on windows it is important to run these commands from a command shell with admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

The `-u` option you are talking about is actually `-U` which means as specified in manual

> Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available version. This process is recursive regardless of whether a dependency is already satisfied.

Now to install `scikit-learn` first make sure you have all the dependencies already installed in order to install this library which are

- Python (>= 2.6 or >= 3.3)
- NumPy (>= 1.6.1)
- SciPy (>= 0.9)
  as mentioned on their [site](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html).

**Alternatively** you might wanna try [Anaconda version of python](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which comes with all these modules/libraries pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the helpful answers. I was able to solve the problem and here is how. First I installed Xcode. I should have clarified that I was trying to install it on a mac. Though I still don't know why I need Xcode, it worked. Second I used the sudo statements: sudo pip3 install -u scikit-learn.